# Python Flask call route from another route with parameters

Tags: python, flask, routes, boolean, flask-wtforms

I am using python flask and I have two  routes. 
The first one contains a form with 3 boolean fields and one submit. 
On submit the second route should be called, forwarding the information which of the 3 booleans is checked.

Thanks for any of your help =)

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def funIndex():
  form = TableForm() #contains form with 3 booleans and one submit
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('index.html', form = form)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    ???
    return render_template('tables.html', ???)


@app.route("/tables")
def funTables():
  if boolean1 = true:
    executeMethod (boolean1)
  if boolean2 = true:
    executeMethod (boolean2)
  if boolean3 = true:
    executeMethod (boolean3)
```

Answer (score 1):

So in your home route you would need to grab the form values and use the flask url_for redirect function:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def funIndex():
      form = TableForm() #contains form with 3 booleans and one submit
      if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form = form)
      if request.method == 'POST':
        //grab your form fields here from the request object
        value1 = request.form['boolean1']
        value2 = request.form['boolean2']
        value3 = request.form['boolean3']
        //redirect to /tables route
        return redirect(url_for('tables', value1=value1, value2=value2, value3=value3))
```

In addition if you go this route your tables route will need to take the parameters of those 3 booleans (here named value1, value2, and value3).

**EDIT:** My fault I noticed you are using a Form class. In that case access the booleans like this

```
value1 = form.fieldname.data
```